Can old version AndroidStudio folder delete in Google folder
My c drive is too crowded, I found that there are many old version AndroidStudio under C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Google.
like:

AndroidStudio2021.2
AndroidStudio2022.2
AndroidStudio2022.3
AndroidStudio2023.1

Can I delete this folder?

Yes, you can delete those old versions of Android Studio folders from C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Google. These folders contain previous installations of Android Studio, and they typically take up a significant amount of space. If you're sure you no longer need those older versions, removing them can free up valuable disk space on your C drive. However, before you delete them, make sure you're not currently using any projects or configurations stored within those older versions, and also ensure you have backups of any important files or settings just in case. Once you've confirmed that you no longer need them, you can safely delete those folders.

The tip "make sure you're not currently using any projects or configurations stored within those older versions" is priceless.
